# Laravel url::assets return "\" after every part in url

Tags: laravel, api

I make an API that return url of some media and file

I returned the url like this

```
$file->url  = URL::asset('storage/files/'.$request->course_segment_id.'/'.$file->id.'/'.$file->name);
```

the URl return like that in Postman

```
"url": " http:\/\/localhost:8000\/storage\/media\/2\/1\/03.png "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without much more information, it looks like the response is encoded in JSON.

If you are using Javascript in your front-end, you can parse the response and then access the data properly formatted.

```
let response='{"url": " http:\/\/localhost:8000\/storage\/media\/2\/1\/03.png "}';
let responseObject=JSON.parse(response);

// responseObject returns a-
// -javascript object: {url: " http://localhost:8000/storage/media/2/1/03.png "}

console.log(responseObject.url);

//> http://localhost:8000/storage/media/2/1/03.png
```

Comment: The problem that this return correct url before, but I think something changed in the configuration but I can't determine that.